# Storing variables in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

This is a super basic question...

I've got a plugin that watches two events, in one event it creates a user. After another event I want it to activate that user.

How do I get/store/pass the id of the newly created user from the first event to the second?

```
public function init()
{
    craft()->on('thing.beforeEvent', function(Event $event){
        // Save the new user if they're not already a user
        if(!craft()->userSession->getUser()){
            $newUser = new UserModel;

            $newUser->firstName = craft()->request->getPost('firstName');
            $newUser->lastName  = craft()->request->getPost('lastName');
            $newUser->username  = craft()->request->getPost('username');
            $newUser->email     = craft()->request->getPost('email');
            $newUser->password  = craft()->request->getPost('password');

            $newUserSuccess = craft()->users->saveUser($newUser);
            if (!$newUserSuccess)
            {
                Craft::log('Couldn’t save the new user', LogLevel::Error);
            }
        }
    });

    craft()->on('thing.afterEvent', function(Event $event){
        // Activate the new user if they're not already a user
        //if(!craft()->userSession->getUser()){
        //  craft()->users->activateUser();
        //}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a private variable inside your class, `private $userId = NULL`

After you've saved the user in the first method, update the variable `$this->userId = $user->id`

In the second method grab the user by using the variable `$user = craft()->users->getUserById($this->userId);`

I haven't actually tested the code, but it might do the trick :)

EDIT: You might want to make a null-check before attempting to fetch the user, to ensure that it doesn't break if it tries to run it while the variable is still `NULL`